# Getting Video Unavailable - When upload videos via api

Tags: azure-video-indexer

From last couple of days, I am seeing video unavailable for all the videos uploaded to azure media portal via api, but if I upload the same videos from videoindexer.ai website everything works as expected. Is there anything changed in recent times with api
P.S. : I am using trail account.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "azure media portal"?
It would help if you could provide the URL you get video unavailable from?

Comment: I am using Azure video analyser api at https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/ to upload videos to my trail account

Comment: My accountid is d54c6fea-5200-40e1-86b0-9add5aba7cb7

Comment: @DineshKumar what is the &streamingPreset you are passing in the upload API call?

Comment: @ItaiNorman : I am passing streamingpreset as default, Should I change it something else ?

Comment: @ItaiNorman : tried changing streampreset to different values, still videos are coming as unavailable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the've updated the  videoindexerapi last week.

We've ran into the same issue. Also it looks like "callbackUrl" parameter in the video upload request is now mandatory but the docs suggest it's optional.

I assume there is another change that causes the "video unavailable" error.

Comment: Tried addin callbackurl as well, but still the videos are failing, I am getting 200 in response i.e. video uploads successfully but state is always failed, below is response header I am getting so that you guys can trace                                                                                                               x-ms-request-id: 65c262dc-1964-4ef3-a6ad-79f97babbdfb
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
api-supported-versions: 2.0
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 05:28:52 GMT